# android studio - how build different apk from one project

Tags: android

I have a project in android studio.

I want to generate two different apk from the source with just two differences:

1. changing an string in string.xml
2. removing one premission from manifest like this

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```

is this possible or I should duplicate project?

Comment: Build Variants is what you are looking for. This can be achieved using `productFlavors` in gradle. I would suggest looking into that